# How to use cycles in sas macro data step

Tags: macros, sas, sas-macro

I need to use cycles in a sas macro that writes a data step

I have a code that should work but it doesn't. How can i fix it?

```
%macro ci;
data 
%do i=1 %to 3;
  _z%sysfunc(putn(%eval(&i),z2.)) ;
%end;
;
set _06;
%do i=1 %to 3;
  if num="%sysfunc(putn(%eval(&i),z2.))" then output _z%sysfunc(putn(%eval(&i),z2.));
%end;
run;
%mend;

%ci;
```

I'd like to get the following output:

```
data 
_z01
_z02
_z03;
set _06 ;
if num="01" then output _z01;
if num="02" then output _z02;
if num="03" then output _z03;
run;
```

Comment: I don't think you need the %EVAL there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close.  You simply had an extra `;` in your first loop.

You need to change:

```
data 
%do i=1 %to 3;
  _z%sysfunc(putn(%eval(&i),z2.)) ;
%end;
;
```

to:

```
data 
%do i=1 %to 3;
  _z%sysfunc(putn(%eval(&i),z2.)) 
%end;
;
```

Adding `option mprint;` to the beginning of your code would show you the code that was generated from your macro statement and helped you to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

how about If you would use a simpler approach instead of using converting the number to character

```
data _06;
num='01';
output;
num='02';
output;
num='03';
output;
run;

%macro ci;
data 
%do i=1 %to 3;
    _z0&i
%end;
;
set _06;
%do i=1 %to 3;
  if num="0&i" then output _z0&i;
%end;
run;
%mend;

%ci;
```